# How should the "analysis" tag be used?

Tags: discussion, tag-management

In my mind, ideally, there should be a fairly consistent "etiquette", if you will, for choosing tags wherein any two people asking the same question are likely to pick the same tags for that question. With this in mind:

> What is the appropriate use of the [analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis) tag?

This tag's description reads:

> Mathematical analysis. Consider a more specific tag instead: (real-analysis), (complex-analysis), (functional-analysis), (fourier-analysis), (measure-theory), (calculus-of-variations), etc. For data analysis, use (data-analysis).

If I were to ask a question about, say, Bolzano-Weierstrass, I'd choose the [real-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-analysis) tag.  If I were to ask a question about Cauchy's integral formula, I'd choose the [complex-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-analysis) tag.  Once I do so, it seems superfluous to add the analysis tag on top of it.  Should I?  If not, are there *any* scenarios in which one should choose the analysis tag over one of the more specific tags listed in the description above?  If the answer is no, then why do we have the [analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis) tag at all?  In practice, I see this tag used quite inconsistently:

- Some people add both the [analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis) tag as well as a more specific tag.
- Some people add only the more specific tag.
- Some people add only the more general tag.

One reason this is problematic is because some users browse by tag instead of clicking "newest questions".  Moreover, it makes it harder for those who use the "favorite tags" feature to find questions that they'd be interested in answering.   I'm personally unwilling to add it to my favorites because then I'm sure I'd get a lot of "spam" highlights from harmonic analysis or functional analysis—topics I know nothing about.  But if I don't add it, then I'm passing over questions I'd like to answer.

---

**Addendum:** In light of user99914 (a.k.a. John Ma)'s answer, I propose that we edit the tag description to say "Please use a more specific..." instead of "Consider a more specific...".

Answer (score 7):

The answer is: it should never be used. The tag description is there to suggest that the tag should not be used since it is not specific enough.

Previous discussions [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15206/why-is-the-tag-analysis-useful?noredirect=1&lq=1).

If I understand correctly, we do not get rid of "analysis" tag since some universities/institutes do use "analysis" to represent "real analysis". For example, in my undergraduate school, there is a year-long course "elementary analysis" which taught materials which is essentially a first course in real analysis (sequence, limits, continuity, differentiability, Riemann integrability and so on). But it is more common (at least in US) that this is called "real analysis".

If you see a question tagged with "analysis", try to re-tag it using a more specific tag as suggested.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  Given this, should we edit the tag to say "Please use a more specific..." instead of "Consider a more specific..."?

Comment: I am not completely sure. Sometimes I think even stronger words are justified, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119754/382988) for an example. @KajHansen

Comment: I'd support that.

Comment: If it should never be used, shouldn't it be blacklisted instead with a comment hinting to use more specific tags?

Comment: @AndrewT. it is not blacklisted since some schools did use that name (at least I think that is the main reason). But sometimes I do think blacklisting is a good choice.

Comment: @AndrewT.: also, before black listing the tag one should also actually retag everyone of the questions with the analysis tag to something more appropriate. No-one really wants that job of retagging 25000 questions.

Comment: And in terms of "bad tags" go, it is not awful. While better tags could be used, (analysis) still conveys non-zero information. Most of the blacklisted tags are those with zero information or are actively harmful. (Example, I am pretty sure we blacklisted the tag (math).)

Comment: @WillieWong Actually, the tag can be blacklisted even without removing all occurrences. (I only learned about this recently in connection with [another discussion on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28025/can-we-please-have-a-deprecated-tag-feature/28032#28032).) After a tag is blacklisted, the effect is that it cannot be added to new questions, and if a question containing the tag is edited, it has to be removed before the edit can be submitted.

Comment: As a side note, blacklisted tags are listed here: [Which are blacklisted tags and blacklisted phrases?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21966)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: I stand corrected. (This capability probably was made available after I quit as mod, and I spoke with outdated information.)

Comment: I note that there is no (algebra) tag, only more specific ones.  Perhaps we should also consider similarly eliminating the tag (geometry)?

Comment: @GEdgar The tag "geometry" seems to be specific enough for me. I think it is about elementary euclidean geometry (lines, circles, etc) and some elementary projective/hyperbolic geometry.